# Подскажите как организовать структуру web приложения

Tags: java-ee, архитектура, angular2, сборка

Прошу помощи у более опытных людей. 
 Планируем разработать веб приложение **Angular + Java EE**. 
 Приложение должно быть модульным. В данном контексте имеется ввиду: модуль содержит набор REST сервисов на сервере и соответствующий ему набор страниц/виджетов на клиенте. 
 Набор нужных модулей должен указываться при сборке. 
 Например: захотели собрать приложение без админки - выключили модуль админки в главном билд конфиге и получили сбилденное приложение включающее только нужные модули. 
 Хотелось бы получить одну из описанных ниже структур. Для сборки планируем использовать maven или gradle. 
 Сталкивался ли кто-либо с подобной задачей? Любая информация или литература будут полезны. Странно, но пока не нашел примеров похожей архитектуры. Складывается впечатление, что так обычно не делают, но опять же непонятно почему. Может быть это не реально в следствии каких-то подводных камней? 
* Опыта работы с Angular пока абсолютно нет, поэтому могу что-то понимать неверно.

```
App-|
    |
    |-moduleA-|
    |         |
    |         |-server 
    |         |
    |         |-client
    |
    |-moduleB-|
              |
              |-server 
              |
              |-client


App-|
    |
    |-client-|
    |        |
    |        |-moduleA 
    |        |
    |        |-moduleB
    |
    |-server-|
             |
             |-moduleA 
             |
             |-moduleB
```

Comment: посмотри в сторону env ангуляра при создании через cli, анугляр позволяет бутстрапить то, что тебе нужно и когда нужно и билдить естессно. По вашей схеме смахивает что вы хотите сделать солянку те приложение фронта должно крутиться на вашем серваке(java)?

Comment: @Artsiom, да всё верно. Фронтенд и бэкэнд жестко связаны и будут находиться на одном сервере.

Comment: я слабо себе представляю как maven или gradle будет компилить angular приложение) Я бы вам посоветовал делать фронт отдельным приложением со своим блек джеком и..., а рест отдельно и компилить естественно отдельно

Comment: @Artsiom maven'у всё равно чем заниматься, можно его даже кофе научить варить, только плагин придётся написать) А жесткая связность нам необходима. Мы уже сталкивались с проблемами, когда на сервере удалили какой-то сервис или переименовали переменную, а на клиенте забыли сделать соответтвующие изменение. GWT в этом плане был очень хорош: общие клиент-серверные DTO, константы, даже тулзы можно было писать общие. Но минусов у него тоже хватает, да и отмирает он уже.

Comment: JSF тоже неплохо подходит чтобы решить проблемы жесткой связи фронтенда и бэкэнда, но даже разработчики JSF признают, что в 2017 году не стали бы использовать JSF для новых проктов... Angular вроде выглядит довольно перспективно, но пока слабо представляю, как его применить для наших задач...